# Custom payment method refers directly to success page - Magento

Tags: magento

I cant find any documentation on what model method is called when you press the 'Place order' button.
It should be the 'capture' method.

I did this:

```
<?php 
class Company_Paymentmodule_Model_Payment extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
{   
        protected $_code = 'paymentmodule';

        protected $_isGateway               = TRUE;
        protected $_canAuthorize            = FALSE;
        protected $_canUseCheckout          = TRUE;
        protected $_canCapture              = TRUE;
        protected $_canUseInternal          = FALSE;
        protected $_canUseForMultishipping  = FALSE;
        protected $_canRefund               = FALSE;
        public function __construct()
        { 
            parent::__construct();

        }
        public function capture(Varien_Object $payment, $amount)
        {
         die();
        }
}
?>
```

But its not dying at all.
It just directly refers to the success page and inserts the order to the database.
It does call this model cause when i call a DIE in the construct the Onepage checkout page directly dies.

Any idea whats going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to redirect to some payment gateway you need to implement the method 'getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl' in your payment class.
See how `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::saveOrder()` works